# Installing Ubuntu from USB on Linux mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, usb-drive

I'm on Linux minut. I want to install Ubuntu on my mac. Googling for how to install from USB stick I found this guide https://tecadmin.net/how-to-create-bootable-linux-usb-using-ubuntu-or-linuxmint/ and step 1 is

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

So I do these three steps, but get an error. I have only been using linux a few hours and I'm very bad at interpreting the command line error messages. **What do the message after "E:" mean mean and how do I resolve this problem?**

First, add apt repository

```
jacob@jacob-linux ~ $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
[sudo] password for jacob: 
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 UNetbootin http://unetbootin.github.io/ is a cross-platform utility that can create Live USB systems and can load a variety of system utilities or install various Linux distributions and other operating systems without a CD.

Homepage: http://unetbootin.github.io/
Wiki: http://unetbootin.wiki.sourceforge.net/
Downloads: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=222386
Sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin
Launchpad: http://launchpad.net/unetbootin
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.EYA8k2K63S --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FC91AE7E
gpg: requesting key FC91AE7E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key FC91AE7E: public key "Launchpad PPA for Geza Kovacs" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Second, apt-get update

```
jacob@jacob-linux ~ $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15,4 kB]                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65,9 kB]             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65,9 kB]           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa InRelease                                  
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa InRelease                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa Release.gpg                             
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [995 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages               
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources [816 B]                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [835 B]              
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [628 kB]  
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [841 B]               
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa Release                                 
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa Release                                    
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [17,1 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [401 B]             
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US            
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [417 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/main amd64 Packages                     
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14,0 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [172 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14,3 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [948 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/upstream amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa/main i386 Packages                         
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4 135 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [583 kB]  
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16,9 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [419 kB]
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/import amd64 Packages                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/main i386 Packages                      
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14,6 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [489 kB]   
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7 430 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3 978 B]
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/upstream i386 Packages                  
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [223 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/import i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [13,7 kB]
Ign http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa/main Translation-en                        
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [173 kB]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4 290 B]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [340 kB] 
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [2 201 B]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                    
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [3 491 B]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US              
Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [99,6 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/import Translation-en_US                
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/import Translation-en                   
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/main Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/main Translation-en                     
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/upstream Translation-en_US              
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa/upstream Translation-en                 
Fetched 5 754 kB in 6s (841 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Error!
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_rosa_upstream_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

third, install unetbootin

```
jacob@jacob-linux ~ $ sudo apt-get install unetbootin
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.linuxmint.com_dists_rosa_upstream_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
jacob@jacob-linux ~ $
```

Comment: This really doesn't seem to have anything to do with installing Ubuntu from USB - have you tried searching 'mergelist' on forums.linuxmint.com?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes it does. I run the three commands, and get that error message.

Comment: http://www.ihaveapc.com/2013/12/quickly-fix-mergelist-errors-linux-mint-15-click/

Comment: @steeldriver I did as in the link you sent, but got the following message "W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 1397BC53640DB551"

Comment: OK but is the `E: Problem with MergeList` solved? The key availability should likely be treated as a separate issue

Comment: For the second command I got error message "Fetched 4 567 kB in 7s (647 kB/s)                                              
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: For the third command I got error message "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: Did you close the Mint "Software Sources" application first? Only one process can be accessing the package system at a time.

Comment: Now I have restarted my computer even. Now I get this: jacob@jacob-linux ~ $ sudo apt-get install unetbootin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be installed
 unetbootin : Depends: p7zip-full but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I solved this by booting from Ubuntu instead of Linux mint, using the very same computer. Everything worked as it is supposed to.